# Blueprint CSS compressor Script, how do I use it?

Tags: css, blueprint-css

There's talk of this compressor script for blueprint css, where you can change the total number of pixels, or include fancy-type etc, but I've never figured out how to use it. All I can ever use is the vanilla version of Blueprint, and in this case, my site is only 900 px wide, so I can;t use Blueprint at all until I remake it for 900px format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Compass](http://compass-style.org/) enables you to use Blueprint, YUI or 960 GS along with Sass. It also has support for custom Blueprint layouts. Please view the [screencast](http://vimeo.com/4335944) to get a better idea of what Compass is.

Comment: No, see, I don't want to use a different program, there is a lin e in grid .css
 
 If you need fewer or more columns, namespaces or semantic
 element names, use the compressor script (lib/compress.rb)
 
Which I would use, but I don't know waht a .rb is, or how to use it or throw variables at it.

Comment: A .rb file is (mostly) a file containing a Ruby program. You should be able to execute `lib/compress.rb` file by: `ruby lib/compress.rb` and then pass command-line arguments to it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. I wanted to change Grid.css to reflect my site width of 850px instead of 950px, as well as include the fancy type plugin. You can output custom css files from the command line by typing ruby lib/compress.rb like above, and passing it variables. however, if you want to include plugins, you have to create a YAML file with the new settings. Josh Clayton was nice enough to include a sample config YAML file, so I jsut changed that from:

```
project1:
  path: /path/to/my/project/stylesheets
  namespace: custom-namespace-1-
  custom_css:
    ie.css:
      - custom-ie.css
    print.css:
      - docs.css
      - my-print-styles.css
    screen.css:
      - subfolder-of-stylesheets/sub_css.css
  custom_layout:
    column_count: 12
    column_width: 70
    gutter_width: 10
  plugins:
    - fancy-type
    - buttons
project2:
  path: /path/to/different/stylesheets
  namespace: different-namespace-
  custom_css:
    screen.css:
      - custom_screen.css
  semantic_classes:
    "#footer, #header": ".span-24, div.span-24" 
    "#content": ".span-17, div.span-17, div.colborder" 
    "#extra-content": ".span-6, div.span-6" 
    "div#navigation": "div.span_24, .span-24" 
    "div.section, div.entry, .feeds": ".span-6 div.span-6" 
project3:
  path: /path/to/another/projects/styles
```

to something much simpler, this:

```
MySite:
  path: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MySite/
  custom_layout:
    column_count: 12
    column_width: 60
    gutter_width: 10
  plugins:
    - fancy-type
    - buttons
```

And then I run compress.rb -p MySite